# How to define the getPrice method in this subclass?

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to determine how I should define the getPrice method. The shirts can range from Small to XXXL and the price varies. The price is determined by the size: $22.99 for XXL or XXXL, and $19.99 for all other sizes.

There are two other classes that I have complied. But the method I need help with only goes with this code.

```
public class TeeShirt{
    private int orderNumber;
    private String size;
    private String color;
    private double price;
    public void setOrderNumber(int num){
        orderNumber = num;
    }
    public void setSize(String sz){
        size = sz;
    }
    public void setColor(String color){
        this.color = color;
    }
    public int getOrderNumber(){
        return orderNumber;
    }
    public String getSize(){
        return size;
    }
    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
}//end
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hampster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Unless someone takes it upon himself to eat hampsters :-)

Comment: What's a hampster?

Comment: As of right now, it returns $0 for all orders. I need to define the getPrice method so that it returns the correct price depending on the size shit ordered. The price is determined by the size: $22.99 for XXL or XXXL, and $19.99 for all other sizes.

Comment: And where are you stuck?

Comment: I need examples of how I should proceed. Should I be writing an if statement? I just want a simple method to distinguish between the two prices.

Comment: @shmosel: a hampster is a genetic cross-breed between a hamster and a hamper. They taste like cheese, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign the price on your `setSize()` function depending on size type.

```
public void setSize(String sz){
    size = sz;
    if(size.equals("XXXL") || size.equals("XXL"){
        price = 22.99;
    }else{
        price = 19.99;
    }
}
```